# Why is my ChartJs grid not matching up with points?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I am making a chart displaying stock data using ChartJs (react-chartjs-2). I have a datapoint for every minute from 9:30am to 3:59pm. When I plot it, my chart looks like the image below. The points don't even remotely align with the grid. The point in the image says 10:16 but the chart positions it between 9 and 10. Why is it like this? The points should also start halfway after the 9 tick since my data starts at 9:30. Does anyone know what I can do to resolve this?

My data is in the format like `x = 2023-02-15 09:30:00-05:00` and `y = 226.145`. I have an option that truncates what is displayed on the tick so instead of displaying the entire datetime format, it only displays the hour.

Here is some of my code:

```
const data = {
  labels: Object.keys(stockdata),
  datasets: [
    {
      data: Object.values(stockdata),
      borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
    },
  ],
};

const options = {
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      position: "top",
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "Chart.js Line Chart",
    },
  },

  pointRadius: 0,
  scales: {
    x: {
      ticks: {
        callback: function (val) {
          const time = parseInt(
            this.getLabelForValue(val).split(" ")[1].split(":")[0] % 12
          );
          return time == 0 ? 12 : time;
        },
        maxTicksLimit: 7,
      },
      grid: {
        color: "#303030",
      },
    },
    y: {
      grid: {
        color: "#303030",
      },
    },
  },
};
```

**React component render:**

```
<Line data={data} options={options} />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the issue is, that your localtime has a date offset off -1 hours, but without seeing the data *(and knowing the offset)*, I can't say for sure.

If this would be the case, you could/would have to convert your **dataset** values. Depending on your dataset and available libraries you could use functions like:

- momentjs:

  ```js
  let localDate= moment.utc("2023-02-01 10:00:00")
      .local()
      .format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
  ```
- vanilajs:

  ```js
  let localDate = new Date(Date.UTC(2023, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0));
  ```

> *You would have to loop through all the x-values / dates entries, to fix this.*

Comment: Hmm, could be but even if it was 9:16 instead of 10:16 the point on the chart does not align with the 9:16 position either. I'll give it a shot though